# how to pass the text value of one html paragraph element to another html paragraph element using javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm trying to pass the text value of one of my html paragraph element to another html paragraph element when the javascript function is called. When this function is called it will load the div element which has the enlarged image and a paragraph content, that is why I'm passing the value from one html paragraph element text value to another paragraph element text value. Here's my code below for your reference:

Javacript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function LoadDiv(url)
 {

    var img = new Image();
    var bcgDiv = document.getElementById("divBackground");
    var imgDiv = document.getElementById("divImage");
    var imgFull = document.getElementById("imgFull");

        img.onload = function() {
        imgFull.src = img.src;
        imgFull.style.display = "block";
        imgLoader.style.display = "none";
    };
    img.src= url;
    var width = document.body.clientWidth;
    if (document.body.clientHeight > document.body.scrollHeight)
    {
        bcgDiv.style.height = document.body.clientHeight + "px";
    }
    else
    {
        bcgDiv.style.height = document.body.scrollHeight + "px" ;
    }

    imgDiv.style.left = (width-650)/2 + "px";
    imgDiv.style.top =  "20px";
    bcgDiv.style.width="100%";

    bcgDiv.style.display="block";
    imgDiv.style.display="block";

     var artcontent = document.getElementById("TextBox2").value;
     document.getElementById("content").value = artcontent;

    /* after I added these two lines of codes below which I thought these could pass the        value but it just ruined my function and not loading anymore the div element I'm calling,it will now only flash the div element for 1 sec without event displaying the content of the artxt2 html paragraph.*/

     var artcon = document.getElementById('artxt1').innerHTML;
     document.getElementById('artxt2').innerHTML = artcon;

    return false;

 }

</script>
```

Asp.Net Source code:

```
<div id="divBackground" class="modal">
</div>
<div id="divImage">
    <table style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">

                <img id="imgFull" alt="" src=""
                 style="display: none;
                height: 500px;width: 590px" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td >
        <p id ="artxt2" runat ="server" ></p>
        <textarea name = "artcont" id = "content" cols ="0" rows ="0" readonly ="readonly" style ="width :590px; height :100px; color :Blue; font-family :Verdana; display :block;"></textarea>  
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="bottom">
                <input id="btnClose" type="button" value="close"
                 onclick="HideDiv()"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I need someone who can assist me and figure out what I'm missing here..Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of .NET? Are you using static client ID's?

Comment: I'm using visual web developer 2008 express ed. I guess so, I thinks I'm using static client ID but not so sure.

Comment: View source of the generated page and check the ID of the P - my guess is it will look very different to what you have specified in your markup

Comment: yeah and in that case or case you should always use <%= Element.ClientID %>

Comment: <p id ="artxt2" runat ="server" ></p>  this is what I'm trying to receive the content from this <p id ="artxt1" runat ="server" style ="white-space :inherit; width :500px; " ><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Article").ToString() %></p>

Answer (score 0):

Change the name with id.

```
 artxt1 must be an id of a control not name.
 var artcon = document.getElementById('artxt1').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = artcon;
```

Comment: Yes..artxt1 is an id of the control not a name. I double check

Comment: I think you overlooked the textarea control

Comment: replace these two lines with this jquery line;
var artcon = document.getElementById('artxt1').innerHTML;
     document.getElementById('artxt2').innerHTML = artcon;
$("#artxt2").html($("#arttxt1").html());

Comment: [http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_html.asp)

Comment: I used this line $("#artxt2").html($("#artxt1").html()); but still doing the same thing.

Comment: Clean the solution/project and rebuild and close the solution and open then hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var artcon = document.getElementById('<%=artxt1.ClientID%>').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('<%=artxt2.ClientID%>').innerHTML = artcon;
```

When you have runat=server on a control the ID is auto generated by .NET (unless you specifically tell it to use static IDs which I think was only introduced in ASP.NET 4.0)

So you need to use the ClientID property to get the generated ID for the control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx